# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. google api

Tags: asp.net, google-api

why i am getting this error, The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
when i am calling the google api to get the basic user profile.
sometimes this works fine, very few times error appears.

here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessToken;
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "" + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
jsonResp = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

i don't think anything is wrong in the code, then what could be the reason?